# E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start

Tags: android

**When i run app on device then above log in print as error log**
anyone know its application side have problem or device related error ?

```
E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I noticed that on my device, I think it's a universal bug or unnecessary/possibly useful logging within Motorola's code.